# `juju bootstrap` fails getting address

Tags: kubuntu, 17.04, juju, lxd

I am trying to do `juju bootstrap lxd lxd-local` but it fails with the following error:

```
Select a cloud [localhost]: 

Enter a name for the Controller [localhost-localhost]: 

Resolved LXD host address on bridge lxdbr0: 10.122.27.1:8443
no credentials found, checking environment
Adding contents of "/home/lurscher/.local/share/juju/ssh/juju_id_rsa.pub" to authorized-keys
Creating Juju controller "localhost-localhost" on localhost/localhost
Loading image metadata
Looking for packaged Juju agent version 2.2.5 for amd64
Starting new instance for initial controller
To configure your system to better support LXD containers, please see: https://github.com/lxc/lxd/blob/master/doc/production-setup.md
Launching controller instance(s) on localhost/localhost...
 - juju-5d7c6c-0 (arch=amd64)          
Fetching Juju GUI 2.10.2
Waiting for address
ERROR failed to bootstrap model: waited for 20m0s without getting any addresses
```

I am running kubuntu 17.04, juju version 2.2.5-zesty-amd64, both lxd and lxc are version 2.19

While stuck in the waiting for address message, I dumped the contents of `/var/log/cloud-init.log` and it is in [this pastebin link](https://pastebin.com/LdkJ6qgq).

On the other hand, `/var/log/cloud-init-output.log` only has a line:

```
lxc exec juju-a9264f-0 cat /var/log/cloud-init-output.log
Cloud-init v. 0.7.9 running 'init-local' at Wed, 25 Oct 2017 23:50:41 +0000. Up 1.00 seconds.
```

Comment: Did you solve the issue?

Comment: never, I simply stopped trying to configure juju and moved to use `docker swarm`

Answer (score 0):

You need an active DHCP to assign a proper IP to the newly formed controller on the LXD

Comment: how do you do this on bare metal where microstack has been installed